# Uncaught TypeError: .includes is not a function with React Ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a menu that when it is clicked it shows up. This works fine. However I want the menu to close whenever anything but the original menu or item list is selected. When I do this however it returns with the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: _this.dropdownMenu.includes is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.eval (FeedItem.jsx:277)
```

**Visual**

[image]

**Code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components';

const OptionMenu = styled.div `
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: -130px;
    display: ${props => props.showMenu ? 'flex' : 'none'};
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 150px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #EEEFEF;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
    z-index: 100;
`;

const OptionItem = styled.div `
    color: #414141;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    transition: .2s;

    &:hover {
        background-color: #F2F2F2;
    }
`;


class FeedItem extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            showMenu: false
        }

        this.dropdownMenu = React.createRef();
    }

    showMenu = (e) => {
        this.setState({ showMenu: true }, () => {
          document.addEventListener('click', this.closeMenu);
        });
    }

    closeMenu = (e) => {
        if(!this.dropdownMenu.includes(e.target)) {
            console.log('yes')

            this.setState({ showMenu: false }, () => {
                document.removeEventListener('click', this.closeMenu);
            });
        }
    }

    render(props) {
        const { showMenu } = this.state;

        return(
            <Container item={this.props.id}>
                    <UserOptions onClick={() => this.showMenu()} ref={this.dropdownMenu}>

                        <OptionMenu showMenu={showMenu}>
                            <OptionItem>Share</OptionItem>
                            <OptionItem>Something</OptionItem>
                        </OptionMenu>
                    </UserOptions>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

export default FeedItem;
```

I'm using styled-components could this be an issue? Also I've delted most of the parts of the container and have just left the problem areas.

Comment: `includes` is a String and Array method, not a Node method. Maybe you want [`this.dropdownMenu.current.contains(e.target)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains)?

Comment: I crazy thing is I could have sworn I used that! Thank you sir!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`includes` is a [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) and [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method, not a `Node` method.

You can use [`contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) instead:

```
closeMenu = (e) => {
    if (!this.dropdownMenu.current.contains(e.target)) {
        console.log('yes')

        this.setState({ showMenu: false }, () => {
            document.removeEventListener('click', this.closeMenu);
        });
    }
}
```